# Obtain duration since last midnight in time zone

Tags: go, time

I would like to obtain the duration since last midnight in a time zone.

I have tried the following:

```
estLocation, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
nowEST := time.Now().In(estLocation)
midnightEST := nowEST.Truncate(24 * time.Hour)
diff := time.Since(midnightEST)
```

as well as using `Round` instead of `Truncate`.

However, this only sets back the clock by 24h instead of returning the midnight in EST.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the time for midnight by constructing a time from the date:

```
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
now := time.Now().In(loc)
midnight := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
```

Subtract midnight from now to get the duration:

```
d := now.Sub(midnight)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8z47UZSDwXE).  Note that time.Now() is a constant value on the playground.